# Testing a view renders translated content when content is html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, internationalization

Been trying to find out how to write a test that tests that a view renders correct content when the content is translation keys with html. To explain a bit more in detail I have this rspec test:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "application/error_404.html.erb" do
  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    it "should have 'not found text' in #{locale}" do
      I18n.locale = locale
      render
      rendered.should have_content I18n.t(:not_found_html)
    end
  end
end
```

to test that it renders `:not_found_html` for each locale I have available. But the test fails due to that it looks for a string without the html:

```
Failure/Error: rendered.should have_content I18n.t(:not_found_html)
       expected there to be content "Could not find the page or item you tried to view. 
         Please try again and if the problem persists please <a href=\"%{contact_link} \">let us
         know</a> so we can fix this."
       in
         "\n\t\n\t\t\tNot found\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tCould not find the page or item you tried
         to view. Please try again and if the problem persists please let us know so we can fix
         this.\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t"
```

I do not know enough of rails to know how to make this work. I would need some way I guess to render just the I18n string? Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I18n.t(:not_found_html) renders just the string.

You could do:

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |l| 
  I18n.locale = l
  I18n.translate! :not_found_html
end
```

It'd raise an I18n::MissingTranslationData if not found.

Comment: I18n.t(:not_found_html) does not render the string, it translates the string without escaping the html due to the _html suffix.

The problem is NOT that the translation is not found, but that the tests fails due to that what I compare is not equal. So my question is how do I get something that is equal to what is being rendered, or is there any other way of testing this?

I guess I could divide it in into two tests; one that makes sure that the view has the `:not_found_html` key and one that makes sure all translation exists.

Comment: But what do you want to test? Isn't it enough to just test that the key exists.

Comment: I would like to test both, to know that the key is there, that it renders into some readable text and there is content for all supported locales. And it would be very convenient to do in just one test.

Comment: how about ERB.new("<%= I18n.t(:not_found_html) %>").result ?

Comment: Could you please explain how this would help. Where should I have it in my code? `rendered.should have_content(ERB.new("<%= I18n.t(:not_found_html) %>").result)` does not work. The problem is that the output of render is `Please try again and if the problem persists please let us know so we can fix this.` while what I get if using any of the I18n methods are `Please try again and if the problem persists please <a href=\"%{contact_link} \">let us know</a> so we can fix this.` So I would need some way to render the html I get from I18n. Or inspect the view/page before rendering...